# Delphi XE7 VCL Styles and MDI form issue in Windows XP

Tags: delphi, windows-xp, vcl-styles

I am using VCL Styles in my application. For Windows 7 everything is OK, but for Windows XP form is displayed incorrectly, like VCL form on top of the standard Windows form, both forms caption is visible. Example:

[image: screenshot]

And one more problem is with DateTimePicker. When I try to select date, MDI form minimizes and only DateTimePicker component is visible.

These issues do not appear when Windows Classic theme is selected.

Comment: Don't use MDI, it's buggy and its never going to be fixed.  use a docking style instead of an MDI style.

Comment: @Warren It's not buggy. MDI works fine. Docking and MDI are very different.

Comment: Don't use VCL styles on XP. XP is outdated, no longer supported by MS, and it's highly doubtful that EMBT will do any work to fix an issue in VCL styles related to it, especially in a non-current version of the IDE.

Comment: @Ken hits the nail on the head. Of course, XP is unsupported. Why would Emba target it?

Comment: @WarrenP, Everything is buggy.  MDI isn't any more then the rest.  We have been writing and selling MDI apps ever since Delphi 1 (for about 15 years).

Comment: You're welcome to do so.  Unlike Apple, Microsoft never deletes anything from their APIs.  But don't expect much QA to go into making sure they actually work.